# Bundler / Rails cannot find newly installed Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I have searched around quite a bit here already to ensure that this question has not been asked previously. While there have been a plethora of similar cases, I was not able to find anyone else experiencing my situation.

My situation is that Rails / Bundler cannot find any reference to my newly installed Gems. In this instance, Nokogiri.

This is the error I am getting when trying to run `bundle install`

```
Could not find gem 'nokogori (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

This is a brand new install of OS X Yosemite, so I think a core step may have just been missed somewhere?

I have used Thoughtbots "Laptop" script to install all of my dev stuff because there's a tonne of overlap with my usual tools, plus installed Rails after that.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/laptop

Here are the steps I am taking to reproduce the error

Install Nokogiri

```
Lukes-MBP% gem install nokogiri
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.6.6.2
Parsing documentation for nokogiri-1.6.6.2
Done installing documentation for nokogiri after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Add to Gemfile

```
gem 'nokogori'
```

Ensure it's installed

```
Lukes-MBP% whereis nokogiri
/usr/bin/nokogiri
```

And here is my `gem environment` output

```
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5
- RUBY VERSION: 2.2.0 (2014-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin14]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/lukerollans/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/lukerollans/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/lukerollans/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/lukerollans/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/lukerollans/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/etc
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86_64-darwin-14
- GEM PATHS:
   - /Users/lukerollans/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
   - /Users/lukerollans/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
   - :update_sources => true
   - :verbose => true
   - :backtrace => false
   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
   - https://rubygems.org/
- SHELL PATH:
   - /Users/lukerollans/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin
   - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec
   - /Users/lukerollans/.rbenv/shims
   - /usr/local/bin
   - /Users/lukerollans/.bin
   - /usr/local/bin
   - /usr/bin
   - /bin
   - /usr/sbin
   - /sbin
```

This has been bugging me for hours now, so if anyone can shed any light on what I'm doing wrong, that would be super!

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your ruby version using

```
$ rvm list
```

to check your ruby version, and then change to proper ruby version using

```
$ rvm use 2.2.0
```

then install nokogiri using

```
$ gem install nokogiri
```

Comment: I'm new to Ruby, but I believe I'm using rbenv, not rvm